# Windows will not update at all (Error 0x80080005)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have already tried about everything there is to fix this and it still does not work.

I refuse to just reinstall completely because I have no way to back up 400 gigabytes and Microsoft should just have a working product anyway.

About half of everything on my PC is broken and it is becoming unusable.

What do I do?

Comment: `0x80080005  CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE  Server execution failed`.

Comment: You say "already tried about everything" have you tried __DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth__  or downloading an .ISO from Microsoft..."Repair" or an inplace upgrade?

Comment: Please comment on at least a few you things you have already tried. How to do an In-place Upgrade, by Shawn Brink at TenForums.com https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Comment: Yes of course I have done DISM.exe. That is what I meant by "tried everything"

Answer (score 1):

**Disable anti-virus programs**

Turn off your anti-virus. It doesn't matter if you are using Windows Defender or a third-party anti-virus. Temporarily disable them and only then check Windows Update. If your anti-virus is not to blame for error `0x80080005`, be sure to enable it. Do not leave your PC unprotected.

NOTE: don't forget to enable your anti-virus after this. Keeping the system unprotected can lead to virus infections.

**Execute the Windows troubleshooter**

1. Push Windows key + I for Windows Settings
2. Go to the Windows Update section
3. then click on Troubleshoot
4. click on Windows Update and then press Run the Troubleshooter

[image: Windows update]

**Check for corrupted system files and fix error `0x80080005` like this**

Windows Updates may not work due to damaged, missing, or corrupt Windows files. To check this, you can apply a couple of methods. First of all, run a SFC and DSIM check:

1. Click Windows + X and select Command Prompt (as Admin).
2. Type sfc / scannow and hit Enter.
3. Copy and paste the command DISM.exe / Online / Cleanup-image / Scanhealth and hit
   Enter.
4. DISM.exe / Online / Cleanup-image / Restorehealth is the next command you have to enter. Don't forget to hit Enter.
5. Finally, close the Command Prompt and restart the system.

[image: command promt]

**Take complete control over the System Volume Information folder**

1. Right click on the Windows + I keys and select Command Prompt (Admin).
2. Alternatively, open Windows Search and type Command Prompt.
3. Right-click on the Command Prompt option and select Run as Administrator.
4. `cmd.exe /c takeown /f»C:\\System Volume Information\\*» /R /D Y && icacls «C:\\System Volume Information\\*» /grant:R SYSTEM:F /T /C /L`
5. Press Enter to run it.
6. Finally, restart your PC.

[image: Command promt 2]

In case this command has not worked for you, try the alternative methods that appear [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309531/how-to-gain-access-to-the-system-volume-information-folder)

**Restart Windows Update Components**

The Windows Update service consists of four active components, for example, MSI Installer, Windows Update Services, and VITS. If any of them has stopped working, Windows Update will stop working properly and may show errors like `0x80080005`. To fix them, you should restart the Windows Update components following the instructions that appear [HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources)

**Install the required update manually to fix error `0x80080005`**

If you encounter Windows Update error code `0x80080005` during the installation of a particular update, for example Creators Update, the solution would be to navigate to the official Microsoft website and download the update manually. To access the Microsoft Update Catalog, please click on this [LINK](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)

[image: manual wu install]

*I happend to deal with this issue a couple of months ago, tried a couple of the solutions and was able to finally have updates (was stuck on 1809)
i found the solution in spanish so i'm sorry if there's any typo*

Hope it helps!

Comment: None of these work

Comment: @sirgemini have you tried manual update then restart and try again the search for updates from the windows update.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows device does not turn on at all then connect a second HDD or SSD and a USB Install media boot from the USB and then go to repair this PC and in advanced options select restore from image.

At this point it will tell you to select a restore image and now you can copy all of your data from your Windows Device to the attached HDD or SSD.

Install a fresh copy of Windows and copy your data back.

Answer (score 0):

**For me it was a third-party antivirus (AVG) that caused the problem.**

### Symptoms

Windows Update was giving an error:

> [image]
> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x80080005)

The problems it generated:

- Right-clicking on a file in Windows Explorer started loading the context menu and never finished
- Excel was starting, but it could not load very big sheets
- Skype was not starting
- TeamViewer was not starting
- AnyDesk could not connect to another computer

### Tried Remedies

- Running the SFC, which reported that it fixed some files, but to no effect.
- Resetting the Windows Update Components as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-update-error-code-0x80080005/07b6e544-a501-4492-851d-83fcb80e8f2f)
- Running Windows Update Troubleshooter - it started and I waited a few hours, it never finished
- Take ownership of System Volume Information directory

(these are all detailed in [the previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1560831/270677))

### Solution

Then came across: https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-error-0x80080005/

This lists all the above remedies, but only as a second step AFTER disabling the antivirus.

I tried to do that with my third-party antivirus (AVG), but:

- its UI didn't start
- uninstall didn't run
- couldn't even remove it from the registry under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] or [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] - it said operation failed when I tried to delete the registry entry

**Had to restart Windows in Safe mode, then the Uninstall worked for AVG.**
Everything's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all nice and dandy, but [human_rosas answer](https://superuser.com/a/1560831/167207) relegated the presumably most important steps to just a link (and not even that bright, given that it's a copy-paste of an old [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316204006/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) that was targeting XP first and foremost). From an elevated command prompt, this is everything that should be needed in the majority of cases:

```
net stop wuauserv
rd /s /q %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
net start wuauserv
```

If that still wasn't enough to solve the issue, you can further try:

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptsvc   
del "%programdata%\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat
cd /d %windir%\system32
regsvr32.exe atl.dll
regsvr32.exe urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe mshtml.dll
regsvr32.exe shdocvw.dll
regsvr32.exe browseui.dll
regsvr32.exe jscript.dll
regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll
regsvr32.exe scrrun.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml3.dll
regsvr32.exe msxml6.dll
regsvr32.exe actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe softpub.dll
regsvr32.exe wintrust.dll
regsvr32.exe dssenh.dll
regsvr32.exe rsaenh.dll
regsvr32.exe gpkcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe sccbase.dll
regsvr32.exe slbcsp.dll
regsvr32.exe cryptdlg.dll
regsvr32.exe oleaut32.dll
regsvr32.exe ole32.dll
regsvr32.exe shell32.dll
regsvr32.exe initpki.dll
regsvr32.exe wuapi.dll
regsvr32.exe wuaueng.dll
regsvr32.exe wuaueng1.dll
regsvr32.exe wucltui.dll
regsvr32.exe wups.dll
regsvr32.exe wups2.dll
regsvr32.exe wuweb.dll
regsvr32.exe qmgr.dll
regsvr32.exe qmgrprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe wucltux.dll
regsvr32.exe muweb.dll
regsvr32.exe wuwebv.dll
netsh winsock reset
net start bits
net start wuauserv   
net start cryptsvc 
bitsadmin.exe /reset /allusers
```

Otherwise, last but not least:

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptsvc
Ren %Systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore DataStore.bak
Ren %Systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution\Download Download.bak
Ren %Systemroot%\System32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
sc.exe sdset wuauserv D:(A;;CCLCSWRPLORC;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)
```

p.s. unsure if this couldn't also have helped with the `server {E60687F7-01A1-40AA-86AC-DB1CBF673334} did not register with DCOM` error that I had noticed in the event viewer.